# Finding unique terms in Lucene 6.5.1

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to retrieve a list of unique terms from a Lucene Directory. During indexing, I created a Field with a TermVector type:

```
private void addDoc(IndexWriter writer, String content, String title, String id) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("content", content, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("id", id, Field.Store.YES));

    FieldType type = new FieldType();
    type.setStored(true);
    type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
    IndexOptions options = IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS;
    type.setIndexOptions(options);
    Field field = new Field("termVector", content, type);
    doc.add(field);
    writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

This works ok for indexing, but when I try to retrieve the terms using TermsEnum I don't get anything:

```
private void buildVocabularyLucene(Directory directory) throws IOException {
    DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
    Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
    for(String field : fields) {
        if(!field.equals("termVector")) {
            continue;
        }
        Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
        TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();
        BytesRef text = termsEnum.next();
        while((text) != null) {
            System.out.println(text.utf8ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this isn't retrieving the text? I'm using Lucene version 6.5.1.